# TKinter read CSV file and display all values using Canvas generate dynamic buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas

In my CSV File , there are two columns only CountryCode,CountryName.
My requirement is like read csv file values and display the values in table format
with scrollbar option , for each row , one button will display .When click this
button ,it new popup window that display corresponding countryDetails based on the countryCode

Here is my Code below

In my Code, I can able read csv file and display all the values with scroll bar option and
display one button for each row .

Now my question is like ,for example 100 rows in CSV file ,it display 100 button for each row
how to bind the corresponding button with CountryCode and call the function openpopup

```
import csv
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("My Application")
width = 980
height = 600
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width / 2) - (width / 2)
y = (screen_height / 2) - (height / 2)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))
container = ttk.Frame(root)
canvas = tk.Canvas(container)
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)
scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)
canvas.create_window((250, 250), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw" )
canvas.place(x=80,y=400,width=800,height=600)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
container.pack()
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

def read_csvfile():     
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename( title="Open file") 
    with open(filepath) as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
            i=0
            tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text="Country Code").grid(row=i,column=1)
            tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text="Country Name").grid(row=i,column=2)          
           
            for row in reader:
                i=i+1
                Countrycode = row['Country Code']
                Countryname = row['Country Name']    
                tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=Countrycode).grid(row=i,column=1)
                tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=Countryname).grid(row=i,column=2)                          
                ttk.Button(scrollable_frame,  text="ViewCountryDetails "+ str(i)).grid(row=i,column=3)

button = Button(root,text ='Read CSVFile', command = read_csvfile)
button.place(x=40, y=40)

root.mainloop()
```

CSV FILE

```
Country Code,Country Name
25,country1
26,country2
27,country3
28,country3
29,country5
```

Answer (score 0):

well first I would write that function, taking in one parameter, the country code. then add that command to your button:

```
ttk.Button(scrollable_frame,  text="ViewCountryDetails "+ str(i), command=lambda: openpopup(Countrycode)).grid(row=i,column=3)
```

then your openpopup function will take in that country code and can open that popup window

Comment: ttk.Button(scrollable_frame,  text="ViewCountryDetails "+ str(i), command=lambda: openpopup(Countrycode)).grid(row=i,column=3)   . It always takes the last countrycode only . when I clicked first row also, or any row it always display last countrycode that reads from the CSV file.  It didn't take the corresponding countrycode for that which is clicked. Any Help is useful for me

Comment: can you add a sample of ur csv file to the question so I can run it

Comment: Country Code,Country Name
25,country1
26,country2
27,country3
28,country3
29,country5
                 These are my CSV values

Comment: Above are my CSV values.Can you please execute my code

Comment: Country Code,Country Name      --column names    25,country1   26,country2   values

Comment: Now I updated CSV details in my Question itself. Please check

Comment: hmm, thats really weird, not sure why thats happening. sorry not sure how else I could help